# javascript global variable update not working

Tags: javascript, variables, global

I can't get the basic thing working - updating the content of the global variable in the function.

so here is the oversimplified code as example:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script>
      window.mytestip = "Var set as global"; 
      var ConditionVar = 1;

      if (ConditionVar == 1)(function() {
      mytestip = "Var set to Yes";
      });
      else(function() {
        mytestip = "Var set to No";
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p> <span id=mytest>-</span> </p>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('mytest').innerHTML = window.mytestip;

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Why is mytestip not updated?

Here is a jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4bu8gp9f/

Resolution:

Adding () actually resolved the presented code issue.
However my code was nested, and I could not use it.

Instead, I have resolved the problem by setting the local storage variable, and retrieved it back from local storage later on:

in the function: 
    localStorage.setItem("LocalIp", mytestip );

later on in the code:
    mytestip = localStorage.getItem("LocalIp");

Thank you all!

Comment: `else` and `if` are not functions and do not take callback functions. they are scope blocks,

Comment: if (RTCPeerConnection){
        window.mytestip = "Var set to Yes";
      }
      else {
         window.mytestip = "Var set to No";
      }

Comment: If your going to use an `IIFE`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE, don't forget to execute them.. `if (ConditionVar == 1)(function() {
      mytestip = "Var set to Yes";
      })(); `  notice the extra `()` at then end.

Comment: All answers below take out function(){} part - and the issue is that the update does not work within function

Comment: Thanks Keith, extra () did made difference. Let me see how it affects the full code

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like it breaks the rest of the code, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )". I have updated the fiddle fwith a full code: https://jsfiddle.net/4bu8gp9f/9/ , the line 32 is where it is not working ...
The code updates the html element, but I need a variable with the same content to send to a server in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I believe you used functions inside the ifs for a good reason, so if this is the case you just missed the '()' after the inline functions:

```
if (ConditionVar == 1) {
    (function() {
        mytestip = "Var set to Yes";
    })();
} else {
    (function() {
        mytestip = "Var set to No";
    })();
}
```

I've add brackets to organize the code (and recommend always do it)

If it's not the case, follow the other proposed answers.

Comment: as Keith previously added, this does fix the issue in the code provided. However for some reason in the full code it produces error ( as mentioned in the comments above)

Comment: The full code has this in a nested function, and adding () produces error

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
if (ConditionVar == 1) {
    mytestip = "Var set to Yes";
} else {
    mytestip = "Var set to No";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `if else statement` was wrong.

So I tried to do like this.

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script>
      window.mytestip = "Var set as global";
      var RTCPeerConnection = window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;

      if (RTCPeerConnection){
        window.mytestip = "Var set to Yes";
      }
      else{
        window.mytestip = "Var set to No";
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p> <span id=mytest>-</span> </p>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('mytest').innerHTML = window.mytestip;

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel and Paul said as comment try this code :

```
if (RTCPeerConnection) {
    window.mytestip = "Var set to Yes";
 }else 
    window.mytestip = "Var set to No";
 }
```

And don't forget quote on your span id parameter

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

Adding () actually resolved the presented code issue. However my code was nested, and I could not use it.

Instead, I have resolved the problem by setting the local storage variable, and retrieved it back from local storage later on:

in the function: 
     localStorage.setItem("LocalIp", mytestip );

later on in the code: 
     mytestip = localStorage.getItem("LocalIp");

Thank you all!